# selenium safari driver System.NotImplementedException

Tags: selenium, safari, selenium-grid, safaridriver

I am using selenium grid 3.3.1 on mac OS Sierra and run remotely commands from windows (using C# with selenium 3.3.1).
When I tried to use ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable I get the following exception:

System.NotImplementedException was caught
  HResult=-2147467263
  Message=Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
System info: host: '192-0-16-223.yunm.com', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:cb9:60b0:d3e1:6bb5%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.2', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, version=12602.3.12.0.1, cleanSession=true, platform=MAC, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=safari, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 379AE190-A868-44A5-98DF-D8F3A2A8ED3C
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.InternalExecute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.get_Displayed()
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions.ElementIfVisible(IWebElement element)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions.<>c__DisplayClass3b.<ElementToBeClickable>b__3a(IWebDriver driver)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
       at Verint.EUA.Robots.SeleniumManager.BrowserDriver.WaitForElementToBeReady(By by, Int32 timeOutInSeconds)

The element exist and I can found it using findElement.
Does Selenium Proj not impl' all methods??

Hezi

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in safaridriver or Selenium. Please start by filing a bug with the Selenium project, they can further diagnose.